# Write structure with long to array by Marshal

Tags: c#, marshalling

I am trying change this:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    public class Frame : BinaryStruct
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 256)]
        public ulong[] array1 = new ulong[256];
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 256)]
        public ushort[] array2 = new ushort[256];
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)]
        public ushort[] array3 = new ushort[16];
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I8, SizeConst = 16)]
        public long[] iP = new long[16];

        public Frame()
        {
            array1 = new ulong[256];
            array2 = new ushort[16];
            array3 = new ushort[256];
            iP = new long[16];
        }
    }
```

in byte array by this:

```
    public virtual byte[] ToArray()
    {
        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(this);

        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(this, ptr, false);
        byte[] array = new byte[size];
        Marshal.Copy(ptr, array, 0, size);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
        return array;
    }
```

It working without

```
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I8, SizeConst = 16)]
    public long[] iP = new long[16];
```

long iP = new IpAddrees(...).Address

I think problem is UnmanagedType.I8 I was trying I4 yet, but it dont work.

Error:

> ```
> Managed Debugging Assistant 'NonComVisibleBaseClass':' A QueryInterface 
> method call was made requesting the COM-visible class
> interface of the 'Frame' managed class. However, since this class is
> derived from COM invisible 'WS.BinaryStruct', the call to
> QueryInterface will fail. This prevents COM version control rules from
> ```

restricting a base class invisible to COM. '

Comment: I think the issue is with the Pack = 1.  Try Pack = 8.  I usually use a Struct instead of a Class.  The Class add other invisible information that changes the size and could cause issues.

Comment: Unlucky change Pack on 8 nothing change. I added error which is throw. @jdweng

Comment: Did you change from a class to a structure?

Comment: I did it long[] should be UnmanagedType.ByValArray no UnmanagedType.I8

Comment: Is it now working?

Comment: Yes it is working.